# Parsing a Vimeo ID using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, vimeo

How do I parse an ID from a Vimeo URL in JavaScript?

The URL will be entered by a user, so I will need to check that they have entered it in the correct format.

I need the ID so that I can use their simple API to retrieve video data.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As URLs for Vimeo videos are made up by `http://vimeo.com/` followed by the numeric id, you could do the following

```
var url = "http://www.vimeo.com/7058755";
var regExp = /http:\/\/(www\.)?vimeo.com\/(\d+)($|\/)/;

var match = url.match(regExp);

if (match){
    alert("id: " + match[2]);
}
else{
    alert("not a vimeo url");
}
```

Comment: There are many cases where this would fail, mostly related to Javascript navigation. Here are some: http://vimeo.com/channels/167691#15316243
http://vimeo.com/m/#/featured/19403316

Comment: The answer was correct at that time as vimeo didn't use that kind of navigation. A simpler (and more naive) way would of course be to use `/\d+/` as the expression..

Answer (score 26):

```
regExp = /^.*(vimeo\.com\/)((channels\/[A-z]+\/)|(groups\/[A-z]+\/videos\/))?([0-9]+)/
parseUrl = regExp.exec url
return parseUrl[5]
```

This works for all valid Vimeo URLs which follows these patterns:

`http://vimeo.com/*`

`http://vimeo.com/channels/*/*`

`http://vimeo.com/groups/*/videos/*`

Answer (score 8):

If you want to check for Vimeo URL first:

```
function getVimeoId( url ) {

  // Look for a string with 'vimeo', then whatever, then a
  // forward slash and a group of digits.
  var match = /vimeo.*\/(\d+)/i.exec( url );

  // If the match isn't null (i.e. it matched)
  if ( match ) {
    // The grouped/matched digits from the regex
    return match[1];
  }
}
```

E.g.

```
getVimeoId('http://vimeo.com/11918221');
```

returns

```
11918221
```

Answer (score 4):

I think Matilda's is the best answer, but it's a non-working code draft, so merging it with Sean Kinsey's answer we get this working code version:

```
var url = "http://www.vimeo.com/7058755"; //Or any other Vimeo url format
var regExp = /^.*(vimeo\.com\/)((channels\/[A-z]+\/)|(groups\/[A-z]+\/videos\/))?([0-9]+)/;

var match = url.match(regExp);

if (match){
    alert("id: " + match[5]);
}else{
    alert("not a vimeo url");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are OK with only parsing a Vimeo URL like `https://vimeo.com/407943692` you don't need regex. This is simpler imao:

```
let vimeoLink = "https://vimeo.com/407943692";
let url = new URL(vimeoLink);
//Remove leading /
let videoId = url.pathname.substring(1);
```

However users often find links to other formats like these:

```
http://vimeo.com/423630
https://vimeo.com/1399176
http://vimeo.com/423630087
https://vimeo.com/423630087
https://player.vimeo.com/video/423630087
https://player.vimeo.com/video/423630087?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0
https://vimeo.com/channels/staffpicks/423630087
https://vimeo.com/showcase/7008490/video/407943692
```

This is my solution that handles every case I have found:

```
let regEx = /(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?(player\.)?vimeo\.com\/?(showcase\/)*([0-9))([a-z]*\/)*([0-9]{6,11})[?]?.*/;
let match = mediaVideoLink.match(regEx);
if (match && match.length == 7) {
    let videoId = match[6];
}
else {
    //Handle error
}
```

Source:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65845916/3850405

Answer (score 2):

Sure.

You should first check the validity/sanity of the URL with a regex and make sure it matches the pattern you expect. (More about [regex'es here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html))

Next you need that ID number, right? Assuming that it's located within the URL, you can extract that also using a regex ([backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html))

It's all just basically string and regex handling.

Answer (score 2):

```
var Vimeo =
{
    get_video_id: function(url)
    {
        var regExp = /http(s)?:\/\/(www\.)?vimeo.com\/(\d+)(\/)?(#.*)?/

        var match = url.match(regExp)

        if (match)
            return match[3]
    },

    get_video_url: function(id)
    {
        return 'https://vimeo.com/' + id
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function getVimeoId(url) {
    var m = url.match(/^.+vimeo.com\/(.*\/)?([^#\?]*)/);
    return m ? m[2] || m[1] : null;
}

console.log(getVimeoId("http://vimeo.com/54178821"));
console.log(getVimeoId("http://vimeo.com/channels/nudiecutie/57383513"));
```

Answer (score 0):

My Javascript solution:

```
function vimeo_parser(url){
    // var regExp = /http:\/\/(www\.)?vimeo.com\/(\d+)($|\/)/;
    var regExp = /^.*(vimeo\.com\/)((channels\/[A-z]+\/)|(groups\/[A-z]+\/videos\/))?([0-9]+)/;
    var match = url.match(regExp);
    return (match&&match[5])? match[5] : false;
  }
```

My typescript solution for angular 8:

```
  vimeo_parser(url){
    // var regExp = /http:\/\/(www\.)?vimeo.com\/(\d+)($|\/)/;
    var regExp = /^.*(vimeo\.com\/)((channels\/[A-z]+\/)|(groups\/[A-z]+\/videos\/))?([0-9]+)/;
    var match = url.match(regExp);
    return (match&&match[5])? match[5] : false;
  }
```