# How do I get the YouTube video ID from a URL?

Tags: javascript, regex, url, youtube

I want to get the `v=id` from YouTube’s URL with JavaScript (no jQuery, pure JavaScript).

### Example YouTube URL formats

`http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u8nQa1cJyX8&a=GxdCwVVULXctT2lYDEPllDR0LRTutYfW`

`http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u8nQa1cJyX8`

*Or any other YouTube format that contains a video ID in the URL.*

### Result from these formats

`u8nQa1cJyX8`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract parameter value from url using regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280557/extract-parameter-value-from-url-using-regular-expressions)

Comment: That question is only for formats like my second one. But I found an interesting answer there, thanks for sharing it.

Comment: There are a regular expression for that: [http://pregcopy.com/exp/27](http://pregcopy.com/exp/27)

Comment: Can't take any credit for it, but I found this to be pretty extensive: https://gist.github.com/FinalAngel/1876898. It even catches urls as diverse as https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=1p3vcRhsYGo and http://www.youtube.com/v/1p3vcRhsYGo

Comment: **As of 2015:** skip to **[this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452546/javascript-regex-how-to-get-youtube-video-id-from-url/27728417#27728417)**. The other answers are out of date.

Comment: Checkout the javascript module [get-video-id](https://github.com/radiovisual/get-video-id) that will extract the Youtube id from any known Youtube url format (including embed strings). It doesn't use one monolithic regex, but it employs a few regex's to find the different patterns.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

You don't need to use a regular expression for this.

```
var video_id = window.location.search.split('v=')[1];
var ampersandPosition = video_id.indexOf('&');
if(ampersandPosition != -1) {
  video_id = video_id.substring(0, ampersandPosition);
}
```

Comment: this is a usefull function to make it work where you want based on this code.

var video_url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eOrNdBpGMv8&feature=youtube_gdata';

ytid(video_url);

function ytid(video_url) {
    var video_id = video_url.split('v=')[1];
    var ampersandPosition = video_id.indexOf('&');

    if (ampersandPosition != -1) {
        video_id = video_id.substring(0, ampersandPosition);
    }
    
    alert(video_id);
    return video_id;
}​

Comment: does not handle embedded URLs

Comment: also doesn't handle 'share' generated urls- `https://youtu.be/{{video_id}}`

Comment: This regex works well with youtube share and watch url.

`url='https://youtu.be/{{video_id}}'; url.match(/(?:https?:\/{2})?(?:w{3}\.)?youtu(?:be)?\.(?:com|be)(?:\/watch\?v=|\/)([^\s&]+)/); `

Answer (score 546):

I made an enhancement to Regex provided by "jeffreypriebe" because he needed a kind of YouTube URL is the URL of the videos when they are looking through a channel.

Well no but this is the function that I have armed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function youtube_parser(url){
    var regExp = /^.*((youtu.be\/)|(v\/)|(\/u\/\w\/)|(embed\/)|(watch\?))\??v?=?([^#&?]*).*/;
    var match = url.match(regExp);
    return (match&&match[7].length==11)? match[7] : false;
}
</script>
```

**These are the types of URLs supported**

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zM3nApSvMg&feature=feedrec_grec_index
http://www.youtube.com/user/IngridMichaelsonVEVO#p/a/u/1/QdK8U-VIH_o
http://www.youtube.com/v/0zM3nApSvMg?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zM3nApSvMg#t=0m10s
http://www.youtube.com/embed/0zM3nApSvMg?rel=0
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zM3nApSvMg
http://youtu.be/0zM3nApSvMg
```

Can be found in [[http://web.archive.org/web/20160926134334/] 
 http://lasnv.net/foro/839/Javascript_parsear_URL_de_YouTube](http://web.archive.org/web/20160926134334/http://lasnv.net/foro/839/Javascript_parsear_URL_de_YouTube)

Comment: The regex contains a little bug \??v?=? this should just be at the watch part, otherwise you would filter a 'v' if the id starts with a 'v'. so this should do the trick /^.*((youtu.be\/)|(v\/)|(\/u\/\w\/)|(embed\/)|(watch\??v?=?))([^#\&\?]*).*/

Comment: Even cleaner: `/.*(?:youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/`  Then use `match[1]` instead of `match[7]` (which seemed a bit arbitrary to me). Also fixes bug pointed out by WebDev.

Comment: /^.*((youtu.be\/)|(v\/)|(\/u\/\w\/)|(embed\/)|(watch\?))\??v?=?([^#\&\?^\s]*).*/

this will limit it until the space " " so this will work
some text https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S09F5MejfBE some other text

Comment: You realise that this regex is not actually even checking the domain; it's so permissive that the string "v/2g5jg1Q2e6k" is enough to match it.

Comment: How long until YouTube IDs are 12 characters long?

Comment: I tweaked this to make all groups non-capturing apart from the ID group `^.*(?:(?:youtu.be\/)|(?:v\/)|(?:\/u\/\w\/)|(?:embed\/)|(?:watch\?))\??v?=?([^#\&\?]*).*$`

Comment: I think It doesn't work if the url contains "player_embedded"

Comment: Did you know that it's not really perfect, if you put https://www.anything.com/watch?v=jn40gqhxoSY It think it's a youtube url

Comment: Interesting Regex on a PHP question for YouTube IDs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556559/youtube-api-extract-video-id/6556662#6556662

Comment: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=feedrec_grec_index&v=0zM3nApSvMg` this is failling.

Comment: Anyone can extend this reqex and thus people complaining are not making any sense.

Comment: fails on this one `https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=4&v=0zM3nApSvMg`

Comment: check this solution with this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a-XQJHpp5vI

Comment: This does not work on this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=5&v=_uN2aPIdVYI.
Just returns false.

Comment: Wrong result with `https://www.youtube.com/embed/vE3nc7oU704`, because `embed` started ID with `v`.

Comment: This works the best in terms of grabbing the YT id `(?:youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com\/(?:[^\/\n\s]+\/\S+\/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)\/|\S*?[?&]vi?=)|youtu\.be\/)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{11})` and then just get the match using `match[1]`. You can also see the regex match here https://regex101.com/r/TAupB0/1

Comment: when the query params get shuffled (v comes later), it won't work. Example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=19&v=-bVYKXrdTMk

Answer (score 270):

I simplified Lasnv's answer a bit.

It also fixes the bug that WebDeb describes.

Here it is:

```
var regExp = /^.*(youtu\.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/;
var match = url.match(regExp);
if (match && match[2].length == 11) {
  return match[2];
} else {
  //error
}
```

Here is a regexer link to play with:
    http://regexr.com/3dnqv

Comment: just a heads up: this should only be used when you know that you are dealing with a youtube url. I (wrongfully) used it to verify urls as youtube, which caused false positives, e.g. this passes: 'v/2059-9080-5437'

Comment: I'm using now a different Regex that also checks for a youtube domain. I'm not sure if I should update the answer as it's a big change:
/^.*(youtu.be\/|youtube(-nocookie)?.com\/(v\/|.*u\/\w\/|embed\/|.*v=))([\w-]{11}).*/

Comment: When will YouTube switch to 12 characters for the video ID?

Comment: shouldn't the dot in "youtu.be" be escaped?

Comment: you're right @jitbit Thank you. Although it usually works as well without escaping it.

Comment: I just find out that this regex will find a url with "tv" in it, even if it's not Youtube like: http://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp4/cdn.twit.tv/video/tnt/tnt1634/tnt1634_h264m_864x480_500.mp4

Comment: I changed this part |v\/| to |\?v\/|

Comment: I'm not a fan of the overly permissive `[^#\&\?]*` — can't we use a slightly stricter `\w` or `[a-zA-Z0-9_]{11,12}` (to allow for 12-character ids some time in the future).

Comment: @podperson Why would they switch to 12 char IDs? 
Its several billion years off before they run out of possible 11 char IDs.

Comment: This solves the problems with the urls listed below by JW: `/^.*(youtu\.be\/|vi?\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|\?vi?=|\&vi?=)([^#\&\?]*).*/`

Comment: @NickG I don't know what their schema for generating ids is. If it were merely based on unique numbers in base 62 or whatever they wouldn't need 11 character ids, would they? The larger point was that if you're expecting 11 characters of a particular type, put that in the search.

Comment: with respect to when (if ever) youtube will go to 12 character VID's. I SUSPECT they may have chosen 11 because 11x5bits = 55 bits is the closest thing to the maximum JS integer size of 53 bits and the high order character will never use - or _. I could be totally wrong on this but if I'm not then they will stay at 11 until they want to jump to 22 or 24 (which could be the 12th of never). JUST AN OBSERVATION.

Comment: What about http://y2u.be/j4dMnAPZu70 links?

Answer (score 124):

None of these worked on the kitchen sink as of 1/1/2015, notably URLs without protocal http/s and with youtube-nocookie domain. So here's a modified version that works on all these various Youtube versions:

```js
    // Just the regex. Output is in [1].
    /^.*(?:(?:youtu\.be\/|v\/|vi\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|shorts\/)|(?:(?:watch)?\?v(?:i)?=|\&v(?:i)?=))([^#\&\?]*).*/

    // For testing.
    var urls = [
        'https://youtube.com/shorts/dQw4w9WgXcQ?feature=share',
        '//www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/up_lNV-yoK4?rel=0',
        'http://www.youtube.com/user/Scobleizer#p/u/1/1p3vcRhsYGo',
        'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cKZDdG9FTKY&feature=channel',
        'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yZ-K7nCVnBI&playnext_from=TL&videos=osPknwzXEas&feature=sub',
        'http://www.youtube.com/ytscreeningroom?v=NRHVzbJVx8I',
        'http://www.youtube.com/user/SilkRoadTheatre#p/a/u/2/6dwqZw0j_jY',
        'http://youtu.be/6dwqZw0j_jY',
        'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6dwqZw0j_jY&feature=youtu.be',
        'http://youtu.be/afa-5HQHiAs',
        'http://www.youtube.com/user/Scobleizer#p/u/1/1p3vcRhsYGo?rel=0',
        'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cKZDdG9FTKY&feature=channel',
        'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yZ-K7nCVnBI&playnext_from=TL&videos=osPknwzXEas&feature=sub',
        'http://www.youtube.com/ytscreeningroom?v=NRHVzbJVx8I',
        'http://www.youtube.com/embed/nas1rJpm7wY?rel=0',
        'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=peFZbP64dsU',
        'http://youtube.com/v/dQw4w9WgXcQ?feature=youtube_gdata_player',
        'http://youtube.com/vi/dQw4w9WgXcQ?feature=youtube_gdata_player',
        'http://youtube.com/?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ&feature=youtube_gdata_player',
        'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ&feature=youtube_gdata_player',
        'http://youtube.com/?vi=dQw4w9WgXcQ&feature=youtube_gdata_player',
        'http://youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ&feature=youtube_gdata_player',
        'http://youtube.com/watch?vi=dQw4w9WgXcQ&feature=youtube_gdata_player',
        'http://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ?feature=youtube_gdata_player'
    ];
    
    var i, r, rx = /^.*(?:(?:youtu\.be\/|v\/|vi\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|shorts\/)|(?:(?:watch)?\?v(?:i)?=|\&v(?:i)?=))([^#\&\?]*).*/;
    
    for (i = 0; i < urls.length; ++i) {
        r = urls[i].match(rx);
        console.log(r[1]);
    }
```

Comment: Worth noting that many of the above solutions don't cover this wide batch of valid urls, the test script is very helpful, +1!

Comment: Note that this will be fooled by something like "www.engadget.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ", not that it's likely to be a problem though

Comment: It works, but couldnt fixed the issue arising a text with multiple youtube url's
See this https://regex101.com/r/qK5qJ5/1. It should not replace the second url.

Comment: **If you don't want that an empty ID matches**: `^.*(?:(?:youtu\.be\/|v\/|vi\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/)|(?:(?:watch)?\?v(?:i)?=|\&v(?:i)?=))([^#\&\?]+).*` (i.e. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v= will not match)

Comment: What do you mean by "None of these worked on the kitchen sink"?

Comment: did not work for me. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a-XQJHpp5vI

Comment: @Kamlesh I think OP updated the script, I ran  [youtube.com/watch?v=a-XQJHpp5vI](https://youtube.com/watch?v=a-XQJHpp5vI) and it correctly got the id `a-XQJHpp5vI` .

Comment: @rmutalik "everything but the kitchen sink" is an expression in English meaning "everything imaginable." In this case the author is making a reference to "all of the possible URLs."

Comment: To use this in python, just remove the first and last / and put it in a normal string in re.match(pattern, url).groups()[0]

Comment: Seems like it does same thing as @zurfyx https://regex101.com/r/PSnGxw/1
regex `^.*(?:(?:youtu\.be\/|v\/|vi\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/)|(?:(?:watch)?\?vi?=|&vi?=))([^#&?]+).*`

Answer (score 34):

The best solution (from 2019-2021) I found is that:

```
function YouTubeGetID(url){
   url = url.split(/(vi\/|v=|\/v\/|youtu\.be\/|\/embed\/)/);
   return (url[2] !== undefined) ? url[2].split(/[^0-9a-z_\-]/i)[0] : url[0];
}
```

I found it [here](https://gist.github.com/takien/4077195).

```
/*
* Tested URLs:
var url = 'http://youtube.googleapis.com/v/4e_kz79tjb8?version=3';
url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=g-vrec&v=Y1xs_xPb46M';
url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=Ab25nviakcw#';
url = 'http://youtu.be/Ab25nviakcw';
url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ab25nviakcw';
url = '<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Ab25nviakcw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
url = '<object width="420" height="315"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/v/Ab25nviakcw?version=3&amp;hl=en_US"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/v/Ab25nviakcw?version=3&amp;hl=en_US" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="420" height="315" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed></object>';
url = 'http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/Ab25nviakcw/default.jpg';
url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BGL22PTIOAM&feature=g-all-xit';
url = 'BGL22PTIOAM';
*/
```

Comment: TypeScript:


const youTubeGetID = (url: string) => {
  const [a, , b] = url
    .replace(/(>|<)/gi, '')
    .split(/(vi\/|v=|\/v\/|youtu\.be\/|\/embed\/)/);
  if (b !== undefined) {
    return b.split(/[^0-9a-z_-]/i)[0];
  } else {
    return a;
  }
};

Comment: fails for v=nfDGK_WSFro

Answer (score 32):

```regex
/^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|e\/|u\/\w+\/|embed\/|v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/
```

Tested on:

- http://www.youtube.com/v/0zM3nApSvMg?fs=1&hl=en_US&rel=0
- http://www.youtube.com/embed/0zM3nApSvMg?rel=0
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zM3nApSvMg&feature=feedrec_grec_index
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zM3nApSvMg
- http://youtu.be/0zM3nApSvMg
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zM3nApSvMg#t=0m10s
- http://www.youtube.com/user/IngridMichaelsonVEVO#p/a/u/1/KdwsulMb8EQ
- http://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ
- http://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ
- http://www.youtube.com/v/dQw4w9WgXcQ
- http://www.youtube.com/e/dQw4w9WgXcQ
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ
- http://www.youtube.com/?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=dQw4w9WgXcQ
- http://www.youtube.com/?feature=player_embedded&v=dQw4w9WgXcQ
- http://www.youtube.com/user/IngridMichaelsonVEVO#p/u/11/KdwsulMb8EQ
- http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/v/6L3ZvIMwZFM?version=3&hl=en_US&rel=0

Inspired by [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4811367/4464702).

Comment: ^.*(?:youtu.be\/|v\/|e\/|u\/\w+\/|embed\/|v=)([^#\&\?]*).*
will give you the result in group 1

Answer (score 29):

### tl;dr.

Matches all URL examples on this question and then some.

```
let re = /(https?:\/\/)?(((m|www)\.)?(youtube(-nocookie)?|youtube.googleapis)\.com.*(v\/|v=|vi=|vi\/|e\/|embed\/|user\/.*\/u\/\d+\/)|youtu\.be\/)([_0-9a-z-]+)/i;
let id = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l-gQLqv9f4o".match(re)[7];
```

ID will always be in match group 8.

Live examples of all the URLs I grabbed from the answers to this question:
https://regexr.com/3u0d4

### Full explanation:

As many answers/comments have brought up, there are many formats for youtube video URLs. Even multiple TLDs where they can appear to be "hosted".

You can look at the full list of variations I checked against by following the regexr link above.

Lets break down the RegExp.

`(https?:\/\/)?` Optional protocols http:// or https:// The `?` makes the preceding item optional so the `s` and then the entire group (anything enclosed in a set of parenthesis) are optional.

Ok, this next part is the meat of it. Basically we have two options, the various versions of [optional-subdomain].youtube.com/...[id] and the link shortened youtu.be/[id] version.

```
(                                                  // Start a group which will match everything after the protocol and up to just before the video id.
  ((m|www)\.)?                                     // Optional subdomain, this supports looking for 'm' or 'www'.
  (youtube(-nocookie)?|youtube.googleapis)         // There are three domains where youtube videos can be accessed. This matches them.
  \.com                                            // The .com at the end of the domain. 
  .*                                               // Match anything 
  (v\/|v=|vi=|vi\/|e\/|embed\/|user\/.*\/u\/\d+\/) // These are all the things that can come right before the video id. The | character means OR so the first one in the "list" matches.
  |                                                // There is one more domain where you can get to youtube, it's the link shortening url which is just followed by the video id. This OR separates all the stuff in this group and the link shortening url.
  youtu\.be\/                                      // The link shortening domain
)                                                  // End of group
```

Finally we have the group to select the video ID. At least one character that is  a number, letter, underscore, or dash.

```
([_0-9a-z-]+)
```

You can find out much more detail about each part of the regex by heading over the regexr link and seeing how each part of the expression matches with the text in the url.

Comment: Change `/^` to `/^.*` at the beginning to allow this solution to work even in the case of leading white spaces or other garbage.

Comment: Good idea. I just updated the regex to remove the ^ entirely, it's not needed. I've also updated the regexr example as well. Thanks @AlexanderD'Attore

Comment: This is a phenomenal answer. I also appreciate the detail and the huge list of URLs you're testing against. Very useful for a 2021 / 2022 answer :)

Comment: Some improvements would be to allow `m\.youtube\.com` (for mobile), and possibly `youtube\...` (for local top level domains). Also, the now removed `^` at the beginning might be useful for those who want stricter URL-checking. But anyway, this answer is pretty good, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Magnus. I have updated the regular expression to allow for the 'm' subdomain. It's more complete but technically not required as the subdomain was optional. As to the removed ^ I left that up to the person using it as that kind of requirement is task dependent and not in the scope of this answer.

Answer (score 28):

Given that YouTube has a variety of URL styles, I think Regex is a better solution. Here is my Regex:

```
^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|embed\/|watch\?|youtube.com\/user\/[^#]*#([^\/]*?\/)*)\??v?=?([^#\&\?]*).*
```

Group 3 has your YouTube ID

Sample YouTube URLs (currently, including "legacy embed URL style") - the above Regex works on all of them:

```
http://www.youtube.com/v/0zM3nApSvMg?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0
http://www.youtube.com/embed/0zM3nApSvMg?rel=0
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zM3nApSvMg&feature=feedrec_grec_index
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zM3nApSvMg
http://youtu.be/0zM3nApSvMg
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zM3nApSvMg#t=0m10s
http://www.youtube.com/user/IngridMichaelsonVEVO#p/a/u/1/QdK8U-VIH_o
```

Hat tip to Lasnv

Comment: You really need to go back to the drawing board with this one. Yes it matches the above URLs correctly. But it also erroneously matches many other non-youtube-url strings such as: `"domain.com/embed/file.txt"`, `"/tv/"` and `"Has anyone seen my watch?"`. See: [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830387/php-regex-find-all-youtube-video-ids-in-string/5831191#5831191) to a similar question for a much more precise solution.

Comment: I see your point: the above regex is useless to answer the question of "Is this a YouTube URL?" but that wasn't my goal. I have YouTube URLs - I'm merely extracting an ID. Yes, your answer is solid (and covers a use case that mine doesn't).

Comment: you have the same bug i mentioned above with ids beginning with a 'v'

Comment: Thanks @WebDev - do you know if YouTube ever puts a v in the ID (or starts an ID with a "v")?

Comment: Still works as of today (2013-01-25). Here's an example of it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/bcmoney/yBP4J/

Answer (score 21):

I created a function that tests a users input for Youtube, Soundcloud or Vimeo embed ID's, to be able to create a more continous design with embedded media. This function detects and returns an object withtwo properties: "type" and "id". Type can be either "youtube", "vimeo" or "soundcloud" and the "id" property is the unique media id.

On the site I use a textarea dump, where the user can paste in any type of link or embed code, including the iFrame-embedding of both vimeo and youtube.

```
function testUrlForMedia(pastedData) {
var success = false;
var media   = {};
if (pastedData.match('http://(www.)?youtube|youtu\.be')) {
    if (pastedData.match('embed')) { youtube_id = pastedData.split(/embed\//)[1].split('"')[0]; }
    else { youtube_id = pastedData.split(/v\/|v=|youtu\.be\//)[1].split(/[?&]/)[0]; }
    media.type  = "youtube";
    media.id    = youtube_id;
    success = true;
}
else if (pastedData.match('http://(player.)?vimeo\.com')) {
    vimeo_id = pastedData.split(/video\/|http:\/\/vimeo\.com\//)[1].split(/[?&]/)[0];
    media.type  = "vimeo";
    media.id    = vimeo_id;
    success = true;
}
else if (pastedData.match('http://player\.soundcloud\.com')) {
    soundcloud_url = unescape(pastedData.split(/value="/)[1].split(/["]/)[0]);
    soundcloud_id = soundcloud_url.split(/tracks\//)[1].split(/[&"]/)[0];
    media.type  = "soundcloud";
    media.id    = soundcloud_id;
    success = true;
}
if (success) { return media; }
else { alert("No valid media id detected"); }
return false;
}
```

Comment: Nice idea, but it doesn't work on the vast majority of URL formats. Including not matching on any https sites.

Answer (score 14):

Late to the game here, but I've mashed up two excellent responses from mantish and j-w. First, the modified regex:

```
const youtube_regex = /^.*(youtu\.be\/|vi?\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|\?vi?=|\&vi?=)([^#\&\?]*).*/
```

Here's the test code (I've added mantish's original test cases to j-w's nastier ones):

```
 var urls = [
      'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zM3nApSvMg&feature=feedrec_grec_index',
      'http://www.youtube.com/user/IngridMichaelsonVEVO#p/a/u/1/QdK8U-VIH_o',
      'http://www.youtube.com/v/0zM3nApSvMg?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0',
      'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zM3nApSvMg#t=0m10s',
      'http://www.youtube.com/embed/0zM3nApSvMg?rel=0',
      'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zM3nApSvMg',
      'http://youtu.be/0zM3nApSvMg',
      '//www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/up_lNV-yoK4?rel=0',
      'http://www.youtube.com/user/Scobleizer#p/u/1/1p3vcRhsYGo',
      'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cKZDdG9FTKY&feature=channel',
      'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yZ-K7nCVnBI&playnext_from=TL&videos=osPknwzXEas&feature=sub',
      'http://www.youtube.com/ytscreeningroom?v=NRHVzbJVx8I',
      'http://www.youtube.com/user/SilkRoadTheatre#p/a/u/2/6dwqZw0j_jY',
      'http://youtu.be/6dwqZw0j_jY',
      'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6dwqZw0j_jY&feature=youtu.be',
      'http://youtu.be/afa-5HQHiAs',
      'http://www.youtube.com/user/Scobleizer#p/u/1/1p3vcRhsYGo?rel=0',
      'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cKZDdG9FTKY&feature=channel',
      'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yZ-K7nCVnBI&playnext_from=TL&videos=osPknwzXEas&feature=sub',
      'http://www.youtube.com/ytscreeningroom?v=NRHVzbJVx8I',
      'http://www.youtube.com/embed/nas1rJpm7wY?rel=0',
      'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=peFZbP64dsU',
      'http://youtube.com/v/dQw4w9WgXcQ?feature=youtube_gdata_player',
      'http://youtube.com/vi/dQw4w9WgXcQ?feature=youtube_gdata_player',
      'http://youtube.com/?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ&feature=youtube_gdata_player',
      'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ&feature=youtube_gdata_player',
      'http://youtube.com/?vi=dQw4w9WgXcQ&feature=youtube_gdata_player',
      'http://youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ&feature=youtube_gdata_player',
      'http://youtube.com/watch?vi=dQw4w9WgXcQ&feature=youtube_gdata_player',
      'http://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ?feature=youtube_gdata_player'
  ];

  var failures = 0;
  urls.forEach(url => {
    const parsed = url.match(youtube_regex);
    if (parsed && parsed[2]) {
      console.log(parsed[2]);
    } else {
      failures++;
      console.error(url, parsed);
    }
  });
  if (failures) {
    console.error(failures, 'failed');
  }
```

Experimental version to handle the **m.youtube** urls mentioned in comments:

```
const youtube_regex = /^.*((m\.)?youtu\.be\/|vi?\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|\?vi?=|\&vi?=)([^#\&\?]*).*/
```

It requires `parsed[2]` to be changed to `parsed[3]` in two places in the tests (which it then passes with `m.youtube` urls added to the tests). Let me know if you see problems.

Comment: You should add this one in your testing suit since it was problematic and your regexp resolved it for me : https://youtu.be/ve4f400859I . The letter v was stripped out in my previous regexp

Comment: I get false postive for `http://youtu.be/` if I add the `/` it marks it as valid. Using it in `(value) => /^.*(youtu\.be\/|vi?\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|\?vi?=|\&vi?=)([^#\&\?]*).*/.test(value)`

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I haven't updated my example yet (don't have time to test) so anyone using my code please take note :-)

Comment: what about url of type = m.youtube.com

Comment: @MehulThakkar are they otherwise similar to youtube.com urls?

Comment: @podperson: Yes, when you open any youtube url in any mobile browser, it will get converted to this type.

Comment: @MehulThakkar I added a modified version of the regexp at the bottom of the post. I ran the tests after adding some sample urls, and it seems to work, but it hasn't exactly been through QA (unlike the original!)

Comment: @podperson : Thanks for your effort, i will check.

Answer (score 12):

This regex matches embed, share and link URLs.

```
const youTubeIdFromLink = (url) => url.match(/(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.|m\.)?youtu(?:be)?\.(?:com|be)(?:\/watch\/?\?v=|\/embed\/|\/)([^\s&\?\/\#]+)/)[1];


console.log(youTubeIdFromLink('https://youtu.be/You-Tube_ID?rel=0&hl=en')); //You-Tube_ID

console.log(youTubeIdFromLink('https://www.youtube.com/embed/You-Tube_ID?rel=0&hl=en')); //You-Tube_ID

console.log(youTubeIdFromLink('https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=You-Tube_ID&rel=0&hl=en')); //You-Tube_ID
```

Comment: Thank you. I changed it a bit at the end: https://regex101.com/r/bTrei2/1

Comment: @MrMartiniMo Thanks for the heads up but the regex in your link still doesn’t match YouTube IDs that contain hyphen (-). Example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=06w3-l1AzFk. I have updated my answer to match YouTube ID containing any character except the url delimiters.

Answer (score 10):

I have got a **Regex** which supports commonly used url's which also includes **YouTube Shorts**

**Regex Pattern:**

`(youtu.*be.*)\/(watch\?v=|embed\/|v|shorts|)(.*?((?=[&#?])|$))`

**Javascript Return Method:**

```js
function getId(url) {
  let regex = /(youtu.*be.*)\/(watch\?v=|embed\/|v|shorts|)(.*?((?=[&#?])|$))/gm;
  return regex.exec(url)[3];
}
```

**Types of URL's supported:**

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zM3nApSvMg&feature=feedrec_grec_index
http://www.youtube.com/user/IngridMichaelsonVEVO#p/a/u/1/QdK8U-VIH_o
http://www.youtube.com/v/0zM3nApSvMg?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zM3nApSvMg#t=0m10s
http://www.youtube.com/embed/0zM3nApSvMg?rel=0
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zM3nApSvMg
http://youtu.be/0zM3nApSvMg
https://youtube.com/shorts/0dPkkQeRwTI?feature=share
https://youtube.com/shorts/0dPkkQeRwTI
```

**With Test:**

https://regex101.com/r/5JhmpW/1

Comment: Most simple, yet effective solution from this thread

Comment: Not working when it has forward slash at the end

Answer (score 7):

Since YouTube video ids is set to be [11 characters](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html#GettingStarted), we can simply just `substring` after we split the url with `v=`.
Then we are not dependent on the ampersand at the end.

```
var sampleUrl = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JcjoGn6FLwI&asdasd";

var video_id = sampleUrl.split("v=")[1].substring(0, 11)
```

Nice and simple :)

Comment: This one is literally a duplicate of the accepted answer

Answer (score 6):

I have summed up all the suggestions and here is the universal and short answer to this question:

```
if(url.match('http://(www.)?youtube|youtu\.be')){
    youtube_id=url.split(/v\/|v=|youtu\.be\//)[1].split(/[?&]/)[0];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Java Code: (Works for all the URLs:

1. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zM3nApSvMg&feature=feedrec_grec_index
2. http://www.youtube.com/user/IngridMichaelsonVEVO#p/a/u/1/QdK8U-VIH_o
3. http://youtube.googleapis.com/v/0zM3nApSvMg?fs=1&hl=en_US&rel=0
4. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zM3nApSvMg#t=0m10s
5. http://www.youtube.com/embed/0zM3nApSvMg?rel=0"
6. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zM3nApSvMg
7. http://youtu.be/0zM3nApSvMg
8. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zM3nApSvMg/
9. http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=8UVNT4wvIGY

)

```
    String url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zM3nApSvMg&feature=feedrec_grec_index";

    String regExp = "/.*(?:youtu.be\\/|v\\/|u/\\w/|embed\\/|watch\\?.*&?v=)";
    Pattern compiledPattern = Pattern.compile(regExp);
    Matcher matcher = compiledPattern.matcher(url);
    if(matcher.find()){
        int start = matcher.end();
        System.out.println("ID : " + url.substring(start, start+11));

    }
```

For DailyMotion:

```
String url = "http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x4xvnz_the-funny-crash-compilation_fun";

    String regExp = "/video/([^_]+)/?";
    Pattern compiledPattern = Pattern.compile(regExp);
    Matcher matcher = compiledPattern.matcher(url);
    if(matcher.find()){
        String match = matcher.group();
        System.out.println("ID : " + match.substring(match.lastIndexOf("/")+1));

    }
```

Comment: Remove the double quotes from around the Regex pattern in the JavaScript code and it should work.

Answer (score 4):

Slightly stricter version:

```
^https?://(?:www\.)?youtu(?:\.be|be\.com)/(?:\S+/)?(?:[^\s/]*(?:\?|&)vi?=)?([^#?&]+)
```

Tested on:

```
http://www.youtube.com/user/dreamtheater#p/u/1/oTJRivZTMLs
https://youtu.be/oTJRivZTMLs?list=PLToa5JuFMsXTNkrLJbRlB--76IAOjRM9b
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oTJRivZTMLs&feature=youtu.be
https://youtu.be/oTJRivZTMLs
http://youtu.be/oTJRivZTMLs&feature=channel
http://www.youtube.com/ytscreeningroom?v=oTJRivZTMLs
http://www.youtube.com/embed/oTJRivZTMLs?rel=0
http://youtube.com/v/oTJRivZTMLs&feature=channel
http://youtube.com/v/oTJRivZTMLs&feature=channel
http://youtube.com/vi/oTJRivZTMLs&feature=channel
http://youtube.com/?v=oTJRivZTMLs&feature=channel
http://youtube.com/?feature=channel&v=oTJRivZTMLs
http://youtube.com/?vi=oTJRivZTMLs&feature=channel
http://youtube.com/watch?v=oTJRivZTMLs&feature=channel
http://youtube.com/watch?vi=oTJRivZTMLs&feature=channel
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following code to get the YouTube video ID from a URL:

```
url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qeMFqkcPYcg"
VID_REGEX = /(?:youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com\/(?:[^\/\n\s]+\/\S+\/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)\/|\S*?[?&]v=)|youtu\.be\/)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{11})/
alert(url.match(VID_REGEX)[1]);
```

Comment: I had issues with all other regex examples but this one effectively works on the 3 share options people on desktops use. an url from the address bar, an url from the share button and an url from the inline share button. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4):

This can get video id from any type of youtube links

```
var url= 'http://youtu.be/0zM3nApSvMg';
var urlsplit= url.split(/^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|embed\/|watch\?|youtube.com\/user\/[^#]*#([^\/]*?\/)*)\??v?=?([^#\&\?]*).*/);
console.log(urlsplit[3]);
```

Answer (score 4):

This short piece works for every youtube link I've tried.

```
url.match(/([a-z0-9_-]{11})/gim)[0]
```

https://regexr.com/3nsop

Comment: What about `/(?:[=\/])([a-z0-9_-]{10,12})[&?#\/\n]/gmi`?

https://regexr.com/7hatn

Answer (score 2):

A slightly changed version from the one mantish posted:

```
var regExp = /^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=)([^#\&\?]{11,11}).*/;
var match = url.match(regExp);
if (match) if (match.length >= 2) return match[2];
// error
```

This assumes the code is always 11 characters.
I'm using this in ActionScript, not sure if {11,11} is supported in Javascript. Also added support for &v=.... (just in case)

Comment: this was the only one that worked for a url i was testing with:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=0zM3nApSvMg

Comment: perfect. thanks @Josha 69 link combination i test all is worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

This definitely requires regex:

Copy into Ruby IRB:

```
var url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NLqASIXrVbY"
var VID_REGEX = /(?:youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com\/(?:[^\/\n\s]+\/\S+\/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)\/|\S*?[?&]v=)|youtu\.be\/)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{11})/
url.match(VID_REGEX)[1]
```

See for all test cases: https://gist.github.com/blairanderson/b264a15a8faaac9c6318

Answer (score 2):

One more:

```
var id = url.match(/(^|=|\/)([0-9A-Za-z_-]{11})(\/|&|$|\?|#)/)[2]
```

It works with any URL showed in this thread.

It won't work when YouTube addS some other parameter with 11 base64 characters. Till then it is the easy way.

Answer (score 2):

I made a small function to extract the video id out of a Youtube url which can be seen below.

```js
var videoId = function(url) {
   var match = url.match(/v=([0-9a-z_-]{1,20})/i);
   return (match ? match['1'] : false);
};

console.log(videoId('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ'));
console.log(videoId('https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=17s&v=dQw4w9WgXcQ'));
console.log(videoId('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ&t=17s'));
```

This function will extract the video id even if there are multiple parameters in the url.

Answer (score 2):

If someone needs the perfect function in Kotlin to save their time. Just hoping this helps

```
fun extractYTId(ytUrl: String?): String? {
    var vId: String? = null
    val pattern = Pattern.compile(
        "^https?://.*(?:youtu.be/|v/|u/\\w/|embed/|watch?v=)([^#&?]*).*$",
        Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE
    )
    val matcher = pattern.matcher(ytUrl)
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        vId = matcher.group(1)
    }
    return vId
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a ruby version of this:

```
def youtube_id(url)
   # Handles various YouTube URLs (youtube.com, youtube-nocookie.com, youtu.be), as well as embed links and urls with various parameters
   regex = /(?:youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com\/(?:[^\/\n\s]+\/\S+\/|(?:v|vi|e(?:mbed)?)\/|\S*?[?&]v=|\S*?[?&]vi=)|youtu\.be\/)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{11})/
   match = regex.match(url)
   if match && !match[1].nil?
      match[1]
   else
      nil
   end
end
```

To test the method:

```
example_urls = [
   'www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/dQw4-9W_XcQ?rel=0',
   'http://www.youtube.com/user/Scobleizer#p/u/1/dQw4-9W_XcQ',
   'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4-9W_XcQ&feature=channel',
   'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4-9W_XcQ&playnext_from=TL&videos=osPknwzXEas&feature=sub',
   'http://www.youtube.com/ytscreeningroom?v=dQw4-9W_XcQ',
   'http://www.youtube.com/user/SilkRoadTheatre#p/a/u/2/dQw4-9W_XcQ',
   'http://youtu.be/dQw4-9W_XcQ',
   'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4-9W_XcQ&feature=youtu.be',
   'http://youtu.be/dQw4-9W_XcQ',
   'http://www.youtube.com/user/Scobleizer#p/u/1/dQw4-9W_XcQ?rel=0',
   'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4-9W_XcQ&playnext_from=TL&videos=dQw4-9W_XcQ&feature=sub',
   'http://www.youtube.com/ytscreeningroom?v=dQw4-9W_XcQ',
   'http://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4-9W_XcQ?rel=0',
   'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4-9W_XcQ',
   'http://youtube.com/v/dQw4-9W_XcQ?feature=youtube_gdata_player',
   'http://youtube.com/vi/dQw4-9W_XcQ?feature=youtube_gdata_player',
   'http://youtube.com/?v=dQw4-9W_XcQ&feature=youtube_gdata_player',
   'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4-9W_XcQ&feature=youtube_gdata_player',
   'http://youtube.com/?vi=dQw4-9W_XcQ&feature=youtube_gdata_player',
   'http://youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4-9W_XcQ&feature=youtube_gdata_player',
   'http://youtube.com/watch?vi=dQw4-9W_XcQ&feature=youtube_gdata_player',
   'http://youtu.be/dQw4-9W_XcQ?feature=youtube_gdata_player'
]

# Test each one
example_urls.each do |url|
   raise 'Test failed!' unless youtube_id(url) == 'dQw4-9W_XcQ'
end
```

To see this code and run the tests in an online repl you can also go here:
https://repl.it/@TomChapin/youtubeid

Answer (score 2):

Took me a week , used chatgpt 4 , used claude2 , i used my brain mostly but here you go for any future readers ( thank me later ... ) :

I even included youtube shorts links ....

```
function getYoutubeVideoId(link) {
    const text = link.trim()
    let urlPattern = /https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?[\w\.-]+(?:\/[\w\.-]*)*(?:\?[\w\.\-]+=[\w\.\-]+(?:&[\w\.\-]+=[\w\.\-]+)*)?\/?/g
    let url = text.match(urlPattern)

    if (url && (url[0].includes('youtube') || url[0].includes('youtu.be'))) {
const youtubeRegExp = /http(?:s?):\/\/(?:m\.|www\.)?(?:m\.)?youtu(?:be\.com\/(?:watch\?v=|embed\/|shorts\/)|\.be\/)([\w\-\_]*)(&(amp;)?[\w\?\=]*)?/;
        const match = text.match(youtubeRegExp)
        const fullLink = url[0]
        let videoId = null
        if (match) {
            videoId = match[1]
        }
        return { fullLink, videoId, hasExtraText: text.replace(fullLink, '').trim().length > 0 }
    } else {
        return { fullLink: null, videoId: null, hasExtraText: true }
    }
}

const testYoutubeLinks = () => {
    const randomTexts = [
        'https://www.youtube.com/shorts/FUVDVAtoRAQ',
        'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abcd123456 hello',
        'https://youtu.be/xyz987654 yo',
        'https://www.youtube.com/embed/ouM8z-4Uw4A hi',
        'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wxyz123456&t=30s 123',
        'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_IQwt9ceN8&themeRefresh=1 hii',
        'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_IQwt9ceN8&themeRefresh=1 uhhhu',
        'https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=6MFMju-rdUQ 23324',
        'youtube.com whatever',
        'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zM3nApSvMg&feature=feedrec_grec_index',
        'http://www.youtube.com/user/IngridMichaelsonVEVO#p/a/u/1/QdK8U-VIH_o',
        '   http://www.youtube.com/v/0zM3nApSvMg?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0',
        'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zM3nApSvMg#t=0m10s',
        '   http://www.youtube.com/embed/0zM3nApSvMg?rel=0',
        'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zM3nApSvMg',
        '   http://youtu.be/0zM3nApSvMg'
    ]

    console.log('New Date:', new Date())
    randomTexts.forEach((text) => console.log(getYoutubeVideoId(text)))
    console.log('----')
}
```

The above code gives you the fullLink  , the videoId and a property called hasExtraText in case you want to know if the given text is not only link and has extra text ...

I am using it in production to detect if user has copy pasted youtubelinks in chat:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I liked Surya's answer.. Just a case where it won't work...

```
String regExp = "/.*(?:youtu.be\\/|v\\/|u/\\w/|embed\\/|watch\\?.*&?v=)";
```

doesn't work for

```
youtu.be/i4fjHzCXg6c  and  www.youtu.be/i4fjHzCXg6c
```

**updated version:**

```
String regExp = "/?.*(?:youtu.be\\/|v\\/|u/\\w/|embed\\/|watch\\?.*&?v=)";
```

works for all.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
function getYouTubeIdFromURL($url) 
{
  $pattern = '/(?:youtube.com/(?:[^/]+/.+/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu.be/)([^"&?/ ]{11})/i';
  preg_match($pattern, $url, $matches);

  return isset($matches[1]) ? $matches[1] : false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Chris Nolet cleaner example of Lasnv answer is very good, but I recently found out that if you trying to find your youtube link in text and put some random text after the youtube url, regexp matches way more than needed. Improved Chris Nolet answer:

```js
/^.*(?:youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=)([^#\&\?]{11,11}).*/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function parser(url){
    var regExp = /^.*((youtu.be\/)|(v\/)|(\/u\/\w\/)|(embed\/)|(watch\/)|(\?v=|\&v=))([^#\&\?]*).*/;
    var match = url.match(regExp);
    if (match && match[8].length==11){
            alert('OK');
    }else{
            alert('BAD');
    }
}
```

For testing:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/vDoO_bNw7fc - attention first symbol «v» in «vDoO_bNw7fc»

http://www.youtube.com/user/dreamtheater#p/u/1/oTJRivZTMLs
https://youtu.be/oTJRivZTMLs?list=PLToa5JuFMsXTNkrLJbRlB--76IAOjRM9b
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oTJRivZTMLs&feature=youtu.be
https://youtu.be/oTJRivZTMLs
http://youtu.be/oTJRivZTMLs&feature=channel
http://www.youtube.com/ytscreeningroom?v=oTJRivZTMLs
http://www.youtube.com/embed/oTJRivZTMLs?rel=0
http://youtube.com/v/oTJRivZTMLs&feature=channel
http://youtube.com/v/oTJRivZTMLs&feature=channel
http://youtube.com/vi/oTJRivZTMLs&feature=channel
http://youtube.com/?v=oTJRivZTMLs&feature=channel
http://youtube.com/?feature=channel&v=oTJRivZTMLs
http://youtube.com/?vi=oTJRivZTMLs&feature=channel
http://youtube.com/watch?v=oTJRivZTMLs&feature=channel
http://youtube.com/watch?vi=oTJRivZTMLs&feature=channel
```

Answer (score 1):

i wrote a function for that below:

```
function getYoutubeUrlId (url) {
    const urlObject = new URL(url);
    let urlOrigin = urlObject.origin;
    let urlPath = urlObject.pathname;

    if (urlOrigin.search('youtu.be') > -1) {
        return urlPath.substr(1);
    }

    if (urlPath.search('embed') > -1) {
        // Örneğin "/embed/wCCSEol8oSc" ise "wCCSEol8oSc" return eder.
        return urlPath.substr(7);
    }

   
    return urlObject.searchParams.get('v');
},
```

https://gist.github.com/semihkeskindev/8a4339c27203c5fabaf2824308c7868f

Answer (score 1):

Python3 version:

```
import re

def get_youtube_id(url):
   match = re.match('^.*((youtu.be\/)|(v\/)|(\/u\/\w\/)|(embed\/)|(watch\?))?\?v?=?(?P<id>\w*).*', url);
   return match.group('id')
```

If you are looking to include it in a shell/bash/zsh/fish script, here's how to do it:

```
echo -n "$YOUTUBE_URL" | python -c "import re; import sys; m = re.match('^.*((youtu.be\/)|(v\/)|(\/u\/\w\/)|(embed\/)|(watch\?))?\?v?=?(?P<id>\w*).*', sys.stdin.read()); sys.stdout.write(m.group('id'))"
```

Example:

```
echo -n "https://www.youtube.com/watch/?v=APYVWYHS654" | python -c "import re; import sys; m = re.match('^.*((youtu.be\/)|(v\/)|(\/u\/\w\/)|(embed\/)|(watch\?))?\?v?=?(?P<id>\w*).*', sys.stdin.read()); sys.stdout.write(m.group('id'))"
```

```
APYVWYHS654
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the way to do it with simple parsing would be: get everything starting after the first **=** sign to the first **&** sign.

I think they had a similiar answer here:

[Parsing a Vimeo ID using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916544/parsing-a-vimeo-id-using-javascript)

Comment: And what if the URL doesn't contains `&`?

Comment: Then you must find what's the equivalent delimiter. For instance, the first URL you gave us its the & sign. On the second URL, the end of the string is the delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

We know these characters "?v=" can never appear more than ones but 'v' can appear somehow in the Id Itself so we use "?v=" as delimiter. See it [Working Here](http://jsfiddle.net/dego247/EtbVJ/1/)

```
//Get YouTube video Id From Its Url

     $('button').bind('click',function(){
var 
url='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u8nQa1cJyX8',
videoId = url.split('?v='),//Split data to two
YouTubeVideoId=videoId[1];
alert(YouTubeVideoId);return false;

});

<button>Click ToGet VideoId</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple regex if you have the full URL, keep it simple.

```
results = url.match("v=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)&?")
videoId = results[1] // watch you need.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var video_url = document.getElementById('youtubediv').value;
        if(video_url!=""){
        ytid(video_url);
        document.getElementById("youtube").setAttribute("src","http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+ytid(video_url));
        }
        function ytid(video_url){
            var video_id = video_url.split('v=')[1];
            var ampersandPosition = video_id.indexOf('&');
            if(ampersandPosition != -1) {
                video_id = video_id.substring(0, ampersandPosition);
            }
            return video_id;
        }
```

i hope it can help

Answer (score 0):

```
function youtube_parser(url){
    var match = url.match(/^.*((youtu.be\/)|(v\/)|(\/u\/\w\/)|(embed\/)|(watch\?))\??v?=?([^#\&\?]*).*/);
    return (match&&match[7].length==11)?match[7]:false;
}
```

Shortest and Efficient

Comment: not right, fails vs http://www.youtube.com/e/dQw4w9WgXcQ so please take out the efficient part :)

Answer (score 0):

As webstrap mentioned in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452546/javascript-regex-how-to-get-youtube-video-id-from-url/36306692#comment10575286_8260383):

> It worked if the video start with "v" and it's from youtu.be
>
> The regex contains a little bug `\??v?=?` this should just be at the
>   watch part, otherwise you would filter a `'v'` if the id starts with a
>   `'v'`. so this should do the trick
>
> `/^.*((youtu.be\/)|(v\/)|(\/u\/\w\/)|(embed\/)|(watch\??v?=?))([^#\&\?]*).*/`

Answer (score 0):

I made some slight changes to [mantish's regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9102270/1371786) to include all test cases from [J W's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27728417/1371786) and [matx's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36389802/1371786) answers; since it didn't work on all of them initially. Further changes might be required, but as far as I can tell this at least covers the majority of links:

`/(?:[?&]vi?=|\/embed\/|\/\d\d?\/|\/vi?\/|https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtu\.be\/)([^&\n?#]+)/`

```
var url = ''; // get it from somewhere

var youtubeRegExp = /(?:[?&]vi?=|\/embed\/|\/\d\d?\/|\/vi?\/|https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtu\.be\/)([^&\n?#]+)/;
var match = url.match( youtubeRegExp );

if( match && match[ 1 ].length == 11 ) {
    url = match[ 1 ];
} else {
    // error
}
```

---

For further testing:

http://regexr.com/3fp84

Answer (score 0):

In C#, it looks like this:

```
public static string GetYouTubeId(string url) {
    var regex = @"(?:youtube\.com\/(?:[^\/]+\/.+\/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?|watch)\/|.*[?&amp;]v=)|youtu\.be\/)([^""&amp;?\/ ]{11})";

    var match = Regex.Match(url, regex);

    if (match.Success)
    {
        return match.Groups[1].Value;
    }

    return url;
  }
```

Feel free to modify.

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying Jacob Relkin answer, all you need to do is this:

```
const extractVideoIdFromYoutubeLink = youtubeLink => {
    return youtubeLink.split( 'v=' )[1].split( '&' )[0];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a radically different solution.

You could request the JSON oEmbed document from `'https://www.youtube.com/oembed?format=json&url=' . rawurlencode($url)` and then `thumbnail_url` has a fixed format, match it with a PCRE pattern like `https://i.ytimg.com/vi/([^/]+)`, the first group is the YouTube ID.

Answer (score 0):

try npm package [youtube-id](https://www.npmjs.com/package/youtube-id)

tested on different urls:

```js
const tested = [
  'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={YOUTUBE_ID}&nohtml5=False',
  'https://youtu.be/{YOUTUBE_ID}',
  'www.youtube.com/embed/{YOUTUBE_ID}'
  // ....
]
```

Comment: Link only answer is useless, especially when it will be broken.
Can you elaborate on this a little more?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shortest and the easiest regex for that

```
url = url+'&'    
regex = "v=(.*?)&|youtu.be\/(.*?)&"
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified Regex from the above [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66405602/12830957) by [Dipo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6171922/dipo) with support of Youtube shorts link

```
(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?youtu(?:be)?\.(?:com|be)(?:\/watch\/?\?v=|\/embed\/|\/shorts\/|\/)(\w+)
```

tested Links

```
https://youtu.be/YOUTUBE_ID?123
https://www.youtube.com/embed/YOUTUBE_ID?123
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YOUTUBE_ID?asd

https://youtu.be/YOUTUBE_ID&123
https://www.youtube.com/embed/YOUTUBE_ID&123
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YOUTUBE_ID&asd

https://youtu.be/YOUTUBE_ID/123
https://www.youtube.com/embed/YOUTUBE_ID/123
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YOUTUBE_ID/asd
https://youtube.com/shorts/YOUTUBE_ID?feature=share
```

Please check your test case from here

https://regex101.com/r/BUSmeK/1

Answer (score 0):

```
/^https?:\/\/(?:(?:youtu\.be\/)|(?:(?:www\.)?youtube\.com\/(?:(?:watch\?(?:[^&]+&)?vi?=)|(?:vi?\/)|(?:shorts\/))))([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{11,})/i
```

Here is an optimized regex that finds the video id and follows the YouTube oEmbed definition for embed urls exactly. You can see my matches against test URLs here: https://regex101.com/r/q4mWg1/1

It purposefully doesn't match protocol relative URLs (// instead of https://) and youtube-nocookie.com URLs as those aren't in the oEmbed definition and decrease performance.

You can view the oEmbed spec here:
https://oembed.com/

The offical providers definitions, including the one for YouTube, are here: https://oembed.com/providers.json

I found this very useful on Wordpress sites where I needed to match against the oEmbed URLs in the post content.

Answer (score 0):

if you have array of string from api like this

const link = ["https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nMyBC9staMU"]

const youtubeID = link?.join("").split(`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=`)[1];

console.log(youtubeID) // nMyBC9staMU

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, error messages, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your question with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

### Simply use URL() constructor

```js
const url = new URL('<link>');
url.searchParams.get('v');
```

[Read more about URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)

Answer (score -1):

You can just click the share button and copy the shorten URL.
For example:
This YouTube video got this URL https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3R0fzCw3amM
but if you click the share button and copy the shorten URL, you will get this https://youtu.be/3R0fzCw3amM

Answer (score -2):

```
videoId = videoUrl.split('v=')[1].substring(0,11);
```

Comment: There's no guarantee on the 11 character length.

Answer (score -9):

## Here comes the Powerful Python

```
import pytube

yt = pytube.YouTube("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kwM2ApskJy4")

video_id = yt.video_id

print("video id from utl..",video_id)
```

Comment: No one asked for python

Comment: This was very useful, thank you   The python regex from the pytube source is `r"(?:v=|\/)([0-9A-Za-z_-]{11}).*"`