# Taking away domain name and save position

Tags: javascript, youtube

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript REGEX: How to get youtube video id from URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452546/javascript-regex-how-to-get-youtube-video-id-from-url)

Is there a way with JS to take away like `http://www.youtube.com` and keep the id?

Example: 
`http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y_UmWdcTrrc&feature=plcp` to `watch?v=Y_UmWdcTrrc&feature=plcp`

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't want to get the ID only, just replace `http://www.youtube.com/` with an empty string. Or clarify your question...

Comment: By being more precise. Do you want the Youtube ID or do you want to remove the protocol and host and only keep the path and query string? Also what does "save position" mean in your title?

Comment: You can do it with regex: http://www.youtube.com/.*?, group 1.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do string manipulation via the [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) and [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) javascript functions to get the [URL path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator#Syntax) like so:

```
var url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y_UmWdcTrrc&feature=plcp';
var path = '';

if (url.indexOf('.com/') != -1) {
    path = url.substring(url.indexOf('.com/') + 5);
}
```