# Get string between an symbol

Tags: java

I am extracting a youtube video id from a youtube link. the list looks like this

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mmmc&feature=plcp

I want to get the mmmc only.

i used .replaceAll ?

Comment: Examine Regular Expressions - see the sun tutorials http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html

Comment: did you try request.getParameter("v"); in servlet ? it will give you mmmc directly. that is ofcourse if you use servlets

Comment: It's worth looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452546/javascript-regex-how-to-get-youtube-video-id-from-url?rq=1, which has some pretty well-developed answers for javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: now i know what you are looking for i hope:

```
String url= "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mmmc&feature=plcp";
String search = "v=";
int index     = url.indexOf(search);
int index2    = url.indexOf("&",index);
String found  = url.substring(index+2,index2);
System.out.println(found);
```

Answer (score 3):

Three ways:

1. Url parsing:
   http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html

> ```
> URL url = new URL("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mmmc&feature=plcp");
> url.getQuery(); // return query string.
> ```

1. Regular Expression
   Examples here http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html
2. Tokenize

   ```
   String s = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mmmc&feature=plcp";
   String arr[] = s.split("=");
   String arr1[] = arr[1].split("&");
   System.out.println(arr1[0]);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to use regular expressions, this could be a solution:

```
Pattern p = Pattern
.compile("http://www.youtube.com/watch\\?v=([\\s\\S]*?)\\&feature=plcp");

Matcher m = p.matcher(youtubeLink);

if (m.find()) {
return m.group(1);
}
else{
throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid youtube link");
}
```

Of course, this will only work if the feature will always be plcp, if not, you could simply remove that part or replace it with a wilcard as I did with mmmc

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generic solution (using Guava [`MapSplitter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.MapSplitter.html)):

```
public final class UrlUtil {
    /**
     * Query string splitter.
     */
    private static final MapSplitter PARAMS_SPLITTER = Splitter.on('&').withKeyValueSeparator("=");

    /**
     * Get param value in provided url for provided param.
     * 
     * @param url Url to use
     * @param param Param to use
     * @return param value or null.
     */
    public static String getParamVal(String url, String param)
    {
        if (url.contains("?")) {
            final String query = url.substring(url.indexOf('?') + 1);
            return PARAMS_SPLITTER.split(query).get(param);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final String url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mmmc&feature=plcp";
        System.out.println(getParamVal(url, "v"));
        System.out.println(getParamVal(url, "feature"));
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
mmmc
plcp
```