# Trouble with matching domain at the front and getting video id

Tags: .net, regex

I am trying to modify the following regex to enforce that the domain is either `youtube` or `youtu.be`. This original regex is meant to provide in the 2nd group the id of the video for watching.
E.g. `lVIGhYMwRgs`

**my current test list**

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lVIGhYMwRgs&feature=feedrec_grec_index
http://www.youtube.com/v/lVIGhYMwRgs?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lVIGhYMwRgs#t=0m10s
http://www.youtube.com/embed/lVIGhYMwRgs?rel=0
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lVIGhYMwRgs
http://youtu.be/lVIGhYMwRgs
http://www.example.com/media/embed/83295164
```

**First Regex**

```
(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=)([^#\&\?]*)
```

[image]

The problem is that `example.com` matches!

So I tried modifying the regex to the following to ensure either `youtube` or `youtu.be` are in the url:

```
((youtu.be\/)|(youtube.com\/))(v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=)([^#\&\?]*)
```

[image]
While this solves my `example.com` problem, it does not match the `youtu.be` url.

I have also tried this regex because I think my problem is that `youtu.be` only has a slash and then directly after, the id.

```
(youtube.com\/)(youtu.be|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=)([^#\&\?]*)
```

[image]

and then i tried this which works for `youtu.be` and not much else.

```
((youtube.com\/)|(v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=)|(youtu.be\/))([^#\&\?]*)
```

[image]

How can i fix my modification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've cracked it. Could you verify it once.

*Note: The blank group i.e. ()() is due to easy processing of URLs, so that you need to only consider Group[6] which will give only lVIGhYMwRgs.*

```
((you(tu.be\/()()(.*)|tube.com\/(v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=)([^#\&\?]*))))
```

Comment: I recommend replacing the generic dot with something that will actually test for a dot character, or this will match `youtuBbeQcom` or `youtuBbe` which depending on the type of validation OP is looking for might cause problems.

Comment: @Denomales: It would not cause any problem, rather the dot character will match the video name after youtu.be/. It will never match youtuBbeQcom or youtuBbe.

Comment: this is awesome. Looking forward to dissecting how this works. I have changed my code to use the last group. All are group 8 unless it is the youtu.be address which is group 6. Works great.

Answer (score 1):

Are the IDs always 11 digits? Some options below.

### [Fiddle](http://fiddle.re/5hpk6)

```
http://(www.)?youtu([.]be|be[.]com).*[/=]([A-Za-z0-9]{11})[?#&]*.*$
```

or

```
[=/]([A-Za-z0-9]{11})([?#&]|$)
```

Also found this, which might help
[JavaScript REGEX: How do I get the YouTube video id from a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452546/javascript-regex-how-to-get-youtube-video-id-from-url)

Comment: does not prevent example.com being matched.

Answer (score 0):

## Description

Try this regex out, it looks for either youtube.com followed by a video code of some length upto the next paramater delimiter. Or it follow the youtu.be format and look for a `/` followed by some video code of variable length.

You will need some logic to parse the return strings, in this case group 1 and 2 will match for youtube.com and group 3 and 4 will match for youtu.be.

`(?:(youtube[.]com).*?(?:[?&]v=[^&]*?|[/](?:v|embed)[/]([^&?]*?))(?=$|[?#&]))|(?:(youtu[.]be)[/](.*?)(?=[?&]|$))`

[image]

Note how the www.example.com line is not matched

[image]