# regex to extract youtube video id?

Tags: javascript, regex, get, uri

I have the following regex to extract the youtube video id

```
var regExp = /^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/;
```

For example this would match

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0&desc=gangnam
```

However sometimes the video parameter does not come first and as a result the below does not match.

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?desc=gangnam&v=9bZkp7q19f0
```

How would I include an or clause in the regex to account for the v parameter being preceeded by either an `&` or `?`?

I tried the following but it did not work

```
var regExp = /^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\[?$]v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, the video id is preceded by `v=`, and followed by *either* the end of the string, or `&`. So the regex you're looking for is simply this:

```
var expr = /(?:v=)([^&]+)/;
console.log('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0&desc=gangnam'.match(expr)[1]);
//logs "9bZkp7q19f0"
console.log('http://www.youtube.com/watch?desc=gangnam&v=9bZkp7q19f0'.match(expr)[1]);
//logs "9bZkp7q19f0"
```

You could (but it's not really required) make sure to only match the pattern above in the URI (the bit that follows a `?` in the full string:

```
var expr = /\?.*(?:v=)([^&]+)/;
```

The pattern you've tried is riddled with faults, and to begin fixing that is just too much work, I'd just forget about it. For example:

```
/youtu.be/
```

Matches a literal `youtu` followed by one instance of *any char (that isn't a new line)* (`.`), followed by a literal `be`. Thus it matches `youtu2be`, `youtu#be`, `youtu.be`, even `youtu be`

In response to your comment:

```
expr = /(youtu\.be\/|[?&]v=)([^&]+)/;
console.log('http://www.youtu.be/9bZkp7q19f0'.match(expr)[2]);
//logs "9bZkp7q19f0"
console.log('http://www.youtube.com/watch?desc=gangnam&v=9bZkp7q19f0'.match(expr)[2]);
//logs "9bZkp7q19f0"
console.log('http://youtu.be/9bZkp7q19f0'.match(/(youtu\.be\/|v=)([^&]+)/)[2]);
//logs "9bZkp7q19f0"
console.log(' youtube.com/watch?argv=xyz&v=u8nQa1cJyX8'.match(/(youtu\.be\/|[?&]v=)([^&]+)/)[2]);
//logs "u8nQa1cJyX8"
```

That's all. No need to check for a preceding ? or &...

How does it work:

- `(youtu\.be\/|[?&]v=)`: matches *either* literal `youtu.be/` or *either* `?v=` or `&v=`
- `([^&]+)`: matches (and groups) everything that follows previous match, except for `&`

That means that `youtu.be/<thiswillmatch>&<this will not match>` and `youtube.com/foo/bar/watch?some=params&v=<this will match>&<this won't>`. It doesn't matter if the `v=` bit is directly after the `?` or after an ampersand, all this regex is interested in is finding that `v=`, and matching everythign that follows up until the first `&` that follows. If it can't find the `v=`, but `youtu.be/` is found, the regex will capture everything after the forward slash (ie the vid id)

Comment: This doesn't work for a url like this `http://youtu.be/9bZkp7q19f0`, can you please just suggest how I change the existing part of the regex `?v=` to account for the cases when `v` is prepended with an ampersand `&`?

Comment: I asked a very specific question on what the correct syntax is to change the portion of the regex `?v=` to account for ampersands.  I'm sure it's about 2 characters more to make that change.  Do you know what the correct syntax is?

Comment: @user784637: Yes, but I'm saying you're doing _too much work_. I've added an alternative, way shorter regex that does the same thing... why not use that? But anyhow, intead of `watch\?` try `watch\?.*(?:v=)([^&]+)`, that deals with leading amps and question marks alike

Comment: Yours doesn't work for this `m.youtube.com/watch?feature=related&v=DMua4iJ_VzM&rl=yes&client=mv-google&gl=MX&guid=&hl=en`

Comment: @user784637: Sure it does: `console.log('m.youtube.com/watch?feature=related&v=DMua4iJ_VzM&rl=yes&client=mv-google&gl=MX‌​&guid=&hl=en'.match(/(youtu\.be\/|v=)([^&]+)/)[2]);` logs `DMua4iJ_VzM` in console for me

Comment: My bad, I had a client side check denying it.  I'm going to push this later tonight and let you know how it goes

Comment: @user784637: What check where denied what? Who? Where? When? (stumped)

Comment: What if the url is http://www.youtube.com/watch?argv=xyz&v=u8nQa1cJyX8? How do you differentiate between an argument whose name ends with v and an argument whose name is v?

From: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3452617/784637

Comment: @user784637: I've updated my answer, the only change I had to make was to `|v=)`, which is now `|[?&]v=)`, the full regex is `/(youtu\.be\/|[?&]v=)([^&]+)/`

Comment: Why did this syntax fail when I applied it to the original regex?  I did the same `v=[?$]`

Comment: @user784637: You didn't do the same, you escaped the `[`: copy-pasted from your question: `\[?$]v=`, that makes the opening `[` a literal, not a char-class delimiter

Comment: there is a little problem with urls like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ABCDE123456#t=298. Anyway the workaround is considering the ID length = 11, so the regex is: /(youtu\.be\/|v=)([^&]{11})/

Comment: Thank you for the simple regex :) I would add '?' to the end, like: /(youtu\.be\/|[?&]v=)([^?&]+)/ so urls like https://youtu.be/4i1fbyc0lpw?t=10s (with the time param) will return only the video id.

Comment: @LucasD'Avila: Check the third possible regex I've listed: `expr = /(youtu\.be\/|[?&]v=)([^&]+)/;`

Answer (score 0):

You can incude a positive lookahead to ensure there is a v= ahead of the watch:

```
^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?(v=|.*(?=v=)))([^#\&\?]*).*
```

Edit: Also further looking into your regex you have formatted it wrong and thus will match on embed/. You need to group your statements with brackets when using or statements or it wont include the previous parts of the expression and just match on them alone. You also need to escape special characters like a '.' as this is treated as any character

I have cleaned it up a little bit:

```
/^.*youtu(\.)?be(\.com)?(\/|v\/|u\/\w\/)(embed\/|watch\?(v=|.*(?=v=)))([^#\&\?]+)/
```