# Embedded Youtube video plays first time, but won't replay until page reloaded

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-api, short, replay

This seems to happen only on short videos (mine is 8 seconds long). There is an answer here:

[Embedded YouTube videos won't replay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21002721/short-embedded-youtube-videos-wont-replay)

However, they suggest adding a "Play" button outside the video to replay. My customer does not want this.

Does anyone have a workaround?

Here is my embed code:

```
<iframe width="325" height="196" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/ynQkRUQ-cyU?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

This is exactly what I copy/pasted from the YouTube embed window. The only addition I made was to add "?rel=0" because the customer didn't want the related videos to show after playback. I tried removing this, essentially reverting back to the exact embed code from YouTube, and this did not fix the problem.

Thanks!!!
Scott

Comment: No fix yet? I'm experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

ou can do it adding loop=1 argument in youtube url link

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/GRonxog5mbw?autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=GRonxog5mbw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>​
```

Here is an example
http://jsfiddle.net/4a6d8/