# Youtube Iframe embed - Videos not replaying on touch devices

Tags: video, mobile, youtube, youtube-api, touch

Youtube embedded videos are not replaying on touch devices.

I have searched enough on the web and SO but there is no information about the problem or it's solution. I have created a fiddle which can be tested using chrome's mobile simulator.

I have wasted a lot of time finding a solution for this. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Link to fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/dqpyy53y/4/

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/6XItQTd5pwM?loop=1&rel=0&html5=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Can you list the steps needed to reproduce the error?

Comment: Like I mentioned, **I have created a fiddle which can be tested using chrome's mobile simulator.**. So just open the fiddle, open chrome dev tools, and simulate any mobile device. Let the video finish, once the video ends, it won't replay.

Comment: There were a few devices that could replay successfully (Amazon Kindle Fire HDX/Nokia N9, for example), but for most other devices, it won't replay. For the few devices that could replay, the player looked different than the others, more like the current Youtube player. Have you also seen the issue on a physical device? There's a workaround posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21125216/4241842) where you can put a div on the player and use that to replay the video. If you think it's a bug, you can file a ticket on the [tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/list).