# how to get youtube video id in the url java/etc

Tags: javascript, youtube

how to get youtube video id via javascript can anyone help me

here is the youtube http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mG6DRzIyhOo

Answer (score 0):

For your simple case; use the = javascript String.substr function :

```
var url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mG6DRzIyhOo";
var video_id = url.substr(url.indexOf("=")+1);
```

But since youtube can have a variety of different video url formats, I would recommend using the following solution using regular expressions :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8260383/3303171