# How to get the video id from YouTube url in mobile browser using regex in java

Tags: java, regex, url, video, youtube

I need to get the video id of a YouTube url as follows.
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=9tg3csrFVJw
I referred [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33273137/get-video-id-from-youtube-url-using-android-youtube-api-v3) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24048308/how-to-get-the-video-id-from-a-youtube-url-with-regex-in-java) but I could not find a solution.

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
v=([^\s&#]*)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lIJ3I7/12)

Explanation:

1. `v=` literally matches v=
2. `()` capturing group , in this case group 1, whose value I want to
   capture here
3. `[^\s&#]*` matches everything unless a space or & or #. & is necessary as
   the version id may not be the last parameter. # is necessary as # can be used as bookmark in a url.

You can try that :

```
    final String regex = "v=([^\\s&#]*)";
    final String string = " https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=9tg3csrFVJw";
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

    if(matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
```

[Run it here](http://ideone.com/KCgpjp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
val regex =
        "^((?:https?:)?//)?((?:www|m)\\.)?((?:youtube\\.com|youtu.be|youtube-nocookie.com))(/(?:[\\w\\-]+\\?v=|feature=|watch\\?|e/|embed/|v/)?)([\\w\\-]+)(\\S+)?\$"
```

[Please refer the link to know more.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66786241/10440175)