# Javascript regex return capture group value

Tags: javascript, regex

I am parsing a youtube URL and I want to get the video id but I'm having such a hard time

The only way I could come up with is this

```
href = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-UI86rRSHkg'

...

video = href.replace(/^.*?youtube\.com\/.*?v=(.+?)(?:&|$).*/i, '$1');
```

But I think there must be a better way to do this.

How can I get the value of a capture group in JavaScript regex?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge the `?` in `^.*?youtube` is useless because the `*` means zero or more times, and the `?` means it's optional, which is redundant.

Comment: @Nateowami `?` after `*` or `+` means to not be greedy, to stop at the following-up pattern. So in my case URLs like `youtube.com...` ( missing schema and `www` ) would be valid.

Comment: OK, good point. But without the `?` it would still match cases without scheme or `www`.

Comment: @Nateowami I wasn't sure, that's why I put it there. Still without a question mark I have this inner doubt, don't know why :D

Comment: This question is using a youtube URL as an example but this questions is more generic i.e. `Javascript regex return capture group value`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the YouTube video ID from a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452546/how-do-i-get-the-youtube-video-id-from-a-url)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the matched info use `String#match`:

```
var id = href.match(/\byoutube\.com\/[^?]*\?v=([^&]+)/i)[1];
```

And to make it even safer use:

```
var id = (href.match(/\byoutube\.com\/[^?]*\?v=([^&]+)/i) || [null, null])[1];
```

2nd approach is for the case when `?v=` is missing in `href` variable.

Comment: @Nateowami If the string doesn't match you'll get null back instead of an error.