# Stop chrome extension when youtube is opened

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have made a Chrome extension (di.fm radio player), and I was wondering if there is a way to stop the playback if a tab with youtube video is opened and contionue when youtube tab is closed!?

Answer (score 0):

you will need to declare [permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions) to view the contents of the user's URL bar (maybe look into "activeTab", or "tabs" with ".onUpdate"), and then trigger your pause function when a URL matches a generic youtube format. keep in mind there are multiple formats, so [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9102270/4926817) may be useful.