# How to use an iframe as input for YT.Player

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, youtube-iframe-api

The [docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) say we should use a div container where the `<iframe>` element will be appended.

That works:

```
new YT.Player('player', {
   height: '390',
   width: '640',
   videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
   events: {
      onReady: onPlayerReady,
      onStateChange: onPlayerStateChange
   }
});
```

But I should have an element `<div id="player"></div>` on the page.

Is it possible that if I already have the iframe element with the embedded video to use that iframe in the `YT.Player` constructor?

I would like to have something like this:

```
new YT.Player('iframeId').playVideo();
```

But the `playVideo` isn't there because the player is not loading (I guess that's happening because we are providing the iframe id).

Is there a way to connect an existing iframe with the YT.Player instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a quick hack for it: [get the video id](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8260383/1420197) from the `<iframe>` url, replace the iframe with a div and initialize the player:

```
YTPlayerIframe = (function () {
  function youtube_parser(url){
     var regExp = /^.*((youtu.be\/)|(v\/)|(\/u\/\w\/)|(embed\/)|(watch\?))\??v?=?([^#\&\?]*).*/;
     var match = url.match(regExp);
     return (match&&match[7].length==11)? match[7] : false;
  }
  var __oldPlayer = YT.Player;
  var player = function (id, options) {
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    options.videoId = youtube_parser(el.getAttribute("src"))
    el.outerHTML = "<div id='" + id + "'>test</div>";
    return new __oldPlayer(id, options);
  };
  return player;
})();
```

Then you can use it this way:

```
var myPlayer = YTPlayerIframe("iframe-id", {
   // The videoId option will be taken from the iframe src.
   events: {
      onReady: function () {...}
   }
});
```