# Use Find and Replace to surround keyword Wordpress

Tags: regex, wordpress

I would like to find and replace all the instances of

> https://www.youtube.com/youtube-id

with `[embed]https://www.youtube.com/youtube-id[/embed]`

I considered using regex but I need it to surround the dynamic link, each link has a different id.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

A well documented solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452546/javascript-regex-how-do-i-get-the-youtube-video-id-from-a-url)

Comment: Close, but I need to surround the urls with the shortcode

Comment: Once you find the correct regex to match them, you can simply use that for a replace/substitution.