# Mute YouTube video and autoplay

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

I've got this somewhat working, I'm trying to get the YouTube video on the page to start automatically and be muted on the page load, this is my HTML:

```html
<div class="col-sm-8 product-video-section" id="player">
    <iframe id="ytplayer" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tMnpYFl6-k8" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen wmode="Opaque"></iframe>
</div>
```

JS: (I found this on google)

```html
<script>
        // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
        var tag = document.createElement('script');

        tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

        // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
        //    after the API code downloads.
        var player;
        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('player', {
                height: '195',
                width: '260',
                videoId: 'h3P1OR9gg2Y',
                events: {
                    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });
        }

        // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
        function onPlayerReady(event) {
            event.target.setVolume(0);
            event.target.playVideo();
        }

        // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
        //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
        //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
        var done = false;
        function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
            if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
                //      setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
                done = true;
            }
            event.target.setVolume(0);
        }
    </script>
```

This almost works the way I want it to, the issue is that it's setting the videoID and building the iframe in the JS - I don't want this, I have multiple pages with different videos using this template so I need the ability to have the iframe in the content. Is there a way to do it without setting the id there?

Comment: Do you want all the videos in your page autoplay ?

Comment: Yep! I will only have one video per page, but multiple pages using this code (in a template). I just need it to auto play and be muted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put an attribute `data-videoId` in your html code and be able to use your script for every pages you want like in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/h939dyxr/

**UPDATE**

I have added the following function:

```
 function youtube_parser(url) {
    var regExp = /^.*((youtu.be\/)|(v\/)|(\/u\/\w\/)|(embed\/)|(watch\?))\??v?=?([^#\&\?]*).*/;
    var match = url.match(regExp);
    return (match && match[7].length == 11) ? match[7] : false;
 }
```

from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452546/how-do-i-get-the-youtube-video-id-from-a-url#8260383) to get the video ID directly from the `iframe` url as in the example: https://jsfiddle.net/h939dyxr/2/

Comment: That could work, Is there anyway to do it using the URL that's already being pulled in by the iframe?