# Youtube API V3 get video details by URL

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Recently , the youtube API has been updated to V3 , and I have a question:

How can I get the video details (views, name , description etc..) through Javascript using the url of the video ?

Example :

I have this url https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DQ5w8LBI0kI&ab_channel=YT
and I want to get via Javascript the name and description of it.

How can I do this ?

Comment: Recently? The YouTube API V3 was released in 2013?    Please check the documentation give it a try and come back if you have any issues there is lots of documentation on this **six** year old api.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a detailed information about how to retrieve any kind of data you want in the official documentation of youtube api.[Here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/client-side-web-apps)

Answer (score 1):

The API documentation is quite involved. Two good points to start from are the following:

- [YouTube Data API Overview](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started), and
- [JavaScript Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/js).

Upon reading them -- and surely more for that matter -- do come back with concrete (programming!) questions.

One more hint: the API endpoint that provides you with the information attached to a given video is [Videos.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list). But that doc page becomes meaningful only after you familiarize yourself with the surrounding (programming) environment.

Answer (score 1):

Steps to achieve:

1. See the answer here to see how to [get/parse video Id from a youtube video url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452546/how-do-i-get-the-youtube-video-id-from-a-url).
2. After you get a videoId e.g. DQ5w8LBI0kI, you have to use that in the below API to get views, name, description etc.

   https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics&id=DQ5w8LBI0kI&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]

[See more about this Youtube API here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list?apix=true)