# Search & Match Regex In Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to get youtube video id from a different set of Youtube URL'S. I wrote the below regex for getting video id from a set of youtube URLs. I wrote this in python.

But,

The problem is can we implement the same logic in javascript as well? Since I am quite new to javascript, I need help with it.

```
if data.startswith('https://') or data.startswith('http://'):
        v = re.search("(?:\/|%3D|v=|vi=)([0-9A-z-_]{11})(?:[%#?&]|$)", data)
        data="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+v.group(1)
```

*The above code is in python, data is a Youtube URL.
(I have tried multiple times, but didn't work for me, Hence here.)

Comment: JavaScript has a `startsWith()` method on strings, just like Python does, so that logic is the same.

Comment: [JavaScript regexp tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: appreciate your answer, but what is equivalent for search & group in javascript ?

Comment: `groups = data.match(/regexp/)`. Then use `groups[1]`. Isn't that explained in the tutorial?

Comment: Thank you so much @Barmar , I just don't know why commmutity criticizes question, when someone is in problem ?

Comment: give example of match, or is it deduced from yur regax ?

Comment: Because SO is not a tutoring service, you're expected to try to solve the problem yourself, then come here if you can't get it working.

Comment: @Barmar, I am not saying it at all. I am here because I didn't understand a thing in JS, hence I needed help. (PS: Why would anybody come to SO without any effort?)

Comment: this `[0-9A-z-_]` ? `A-z` include punct ? and [0-9A-z`-`_] is invalid range on most enjins. JS see it as a literal. sloppy

Comment: You say you tried multiple times, so why can't you just post what you tried, so we can explain where you went wrong? That way you'll learn better than us just spoon-feeding you the solution.

Comment: gonna leap off say this was intent `/(?:\/|%3D|vi?=)([\w-]{11})(?=[%#?&]|$)/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaScript equivalent of `startswith` is `startsWith`.

The JS equivalent of `re.search()` is `String.prototype.match()`. It returns an array containing the whole match and captured groups.

`A-z` is an incorrect range in the regexp. Use `A-Z` or `a-z`, along with the `i` modifier to make the regexp case-insensitive.

```js
var data = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-wtIMTCHWuI';
if (data.startsWith('https://') || data.startsWith('http://')) {
  v = data.match(/(?:\/|%3D|v=|vi=)([0-9A-Z-_]{11})(?:[%#?&]|$)/i);
  if (v) {
    data = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + v[1];
  }
  console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Barmar, I really appreciate the efforts you are putting in. Just wanted to share that the above code just doesn't work for this URL: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-wtIMTCHWuI

Comment: You can refer for other URL formats as well : https://gist.github.com/rodrigoborgesdeoliveira/987683cfbfcc8d800192da1e73adc486

Comment: I accidentally deleted the first `(` in the regexp.

Comment: no worries Just worked like charm! Thanks a lot for helping me out. Do let me know if something I could do for you.

Answer (score 0):

JS has the same function so the functionality will be the same check it here [JS startsWith function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith)

Comment: Thanks @Malik appreciate it.

Comment: His main question is about the regexp

Comment: @shriniketdeshmukh actually in JS if you want to get the video ID you don't need regex
check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452546/how-do-i-get-the-youtube-video-id-from-a-url

Comment: @MalikTürk, Yeah, but Youtube has all sorts of URLs like embed,watch, and other. So will it work for every case ?

Comment: if I remember correctly, every YT video ID will be after the `?v=` so it should work with all cases

Comment: @MalikTürk, Actually have a list of Youtube URLs, will share it with you. Please refer https://gist.github.com/rodrigoborgesdeoliveira/987683cfbfcc8d800192da1e73adc486