# Wordpress website: video shown in desktop but not in mobile (window.innerWidth)

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, media

I've a Wordpress website (elvisinvegas.it) with a free theme installed that have an option to render a youtube video on the header. Anyway, the video renders only on desktop view, instead on mobile it renders a background image. I'm a real newbie regarding javascript & c. and I can't find a way to render the youtube video on mobile too.

I've found this function on wp-custom.header.js that it seems related to my issue:

```js
/**
         * Determines if the current environment supports video.
         *
         * Themes and plugins can override this method to change the criteria.
         *
         * @return {boolean}
         */

supportsVideo: function() {
            // Don't load video on small screens. @todo Consider bandwidth and other factors.
            if ( window.innerWidth < settings.minWidth || window.innerHeight < settings.minHeight ) {
                return false; 
            }
```

I tried to change values on it but the mobile version still render the background image instead of youtube video. I guess it is related to CSS too (@media (max-width: 575px) maybe) but can't find where to interact.

I'm really stuck: can someonle please give me some hints to solve this issue?

PS this is the whole wp-custom-header.js code:

```js
/**
 * @output wp-includes/js/wp-custom-header.js
 */

/* global YT */
(function( window, settings ) {

    var NativeHandler, YouTubeHandler;

    /** @namespace wp */
    window.wp = window.wp || {};

    // Fail gracefully in unsupported browsers.
    if ( ! ( 'addEventListener' in window ) ) {
        return;
    }

    /**
     * Trigger an event.
     *
     * @param {Element} target HTML element to dispatch the event on.
     * @param {string} name Event name.
     */
    function trigger( target, name ) {
        var evt;

        if ( 'function' === typeof window.Event ) {
            evt = new Event( name );
        } else {
            evt = document.createEvent( 'Event' );
            evt.initEvent( name, true, true );
        }

        target.dispatchEvent( evt );
    }

    /**
     * Create a custom header instance.
     *
     * @memberOf wp
     *
     * @class
     */
    function CustomHeader() {
        this.handlers = {
            nativeVideo: new NativeHandler(),
            youtube: new YouTubeHandler()
        };
    }

    CustomHeader.prototype = {
        /**
         * Initialize the custom header.
         *
         * If the environment supports video, loops through registered handlers
         * until one is found that can handle the video.
         */
        initialize: function() {
            if ( this.supportsVideo() ) {
                for ( var id in this.handlers ) {
                    var handler = this.handlers[ id ];

                    if ( 'test' in handler && handler.test( settings ) ) {
                        this.activeHandler = handler.initialize.call( handler, settings );

                        // Dispatch custom event when the video is loaded.
                        trigger( document, 'wp-custom-header-video-loaded' );
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        /**
         * Determines if the current environment supports video.
         *
         * Themes and plugins can override this method to change the criteria.
         *
         * @return {boolean}
         */
        supportsVideo: function() {
            // Don't load video on small screens. @todo Consider bandwidth and other factors.
            if ( window.innerWidth < settings.minWidth || window.innerHeight < settings.minHeight ) {
                return false; /* original: false */
            }

            return true; /* original: true */ 
        },

        /**
         * Base handler for custom handlers to extend.
         *
         * @type {BaseHandler}
         */
        BaseVideoHandler: BaseHandler
    };

    /**
     * Create a video handler instance.
     *
     * @memberOf wp
     *
     * @class
     */
    function BaseHandler() {}

    BaseHandler.prototype = {
        /**
         * Initialize the video handler.
         *
         * @param {Object} settings Video settings.
         */
        initialize: function( settings ) {
            var handler = this,
                button = document.createElement( 'button' );

            this.settings = settings;
            this.container = document.getElementById( 'wp-custom-header' );
            this.button = button;

            button.setAttribute( 'type', 'button' );
            button.setAttribute( 'id', 'wp-custom-header-video-button' );
            button.setAttribute( 'class', 'wp-custom-header-video-button wp-custom-header-video-play' );
            button.innerHTML = settings.l10n.play;

            // Toggle video playback when the button is clicked.
            button.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
                if ( handler.isPaused() ) {
                    handler.play();
                } else {
                    handler.pause();
                }
            });

            // Update the button class and text when the video state changes.
            this.container.addEventListener( 'play', function() {
                button.className = 'wp-custom-header-video-button wp-custom-header-video-play';
                button.innerHTML = settings.l10n.pause;
                if ( 'a11y' in window.wp ) {
                    window.wp.a11y.speak( settings.l10n.playSpeak);
                }
            });

            this.container.addEventListener( 'pause', function() {
                button.className = 'wp-custom-header-video-button wp-custom-header-video-pause';
                button.innerHTML = settings.l10n.play;
                if ( 'a11y' in window.wp ) {
                    window.wp.a11y.speak( settings.l10n.pauseSpeak);
                }
            });

            this.ready();
        },

        /**
         * Ready method called after a handler is initialized.
         *
         * @abstract
         */
        ready: function() {},

        /**
         * Whether the video is paused.
         *
         * @abstract
         * @return {boolean}
         */
        isPaused: function() {},

        /**
         * Pause the video.
         *
         * @abstract
         */
        pause: function() {},

        /**
         * Play the video.
         *
         * @abstract
         */
        play: function() {},

        /**
         * Append a video node to the header container.
         *
         * @param {Element} node HTML element.
         */
        setVideo: function( node ) {
            var editShortcutNode,
                editShortcut = this.container.getElementsByClassName( 'customize-partial-edit-shortcut' );

            if ( editShortcut.length ) {
                editShortcutNode = this.container.removeChild( editShortcut[0] );
            }

            this.container.innerHTML = '';
            this.container.appendChild( node );

            if ( editShortcutNode ) {
                this.container.appendChild( editShortcutNode );
            }
        },

        /**
         * Show the video controls.
         *
         * Appends a play/pause button to header container.
         */
        showControls: function() {
            if ( ! this.container.contains( this.button ) ) {
                this.container.appendChild( this.button );
            }
        },

        /**
         * Whether the handler can process a video.
         *
         * @abstract
         * @param {Object} settings Video settings.
         * @return {boolean}
         */
        test: function() {
            return false;
        },

        /**
         * Trigger an event on the header container.
         *
         * @param {string} name Event name.
         */
        trigger: function( name ) {
            trigger( this.container, name );
        }
    };

    /**
     * Create a custom handler.
     *
     * @memberOf wp
     *
     * @param {Object} protoProps Properties to apply to the prototype.
     * @return CustomHandler The subclass.
     */
    BaseHandler.extend = function( protoProps ) {
        var prop;

        function CustomHandler() {
            var result = BaseHandler.apply( this, arguments );
            return result;
        }

        CustomHandler.prototype = Object.create( BaseHandler.prototype );
        CustomHandler.prototype.constructor = CustomHandler;

        for ( prop in protoProps ) {
            CustomHandler.prototype[ prop ] = protoProps[ prop ];
        }

        return CustomHandler;
    };

    /**
     * Native video handler.
     *
     * @memberOf wp
     *
     * @class
     */
    NativeHandler = BaseHandler.extend(/** @lends wp.NativeHandler.prototype */{
        /**
         * Whether the native handler supports a video.
         *
         * @param {Object} settings Video settings.
         * @return {boolean}
         */
        test: function( settings ) {
            var video = document.createElement( 'video' );
            return video.canPlayType( settings.mimeType );
        },

        /**
         * Set up a native video element.
         */
        ready: function() {
            var handler = this,
                video = document.createElement( 'video' );

            video.id = 'wp-custom-header-video';
            video.autoplay = true;
            video.loop = true;
            video.muted = true;
            video.playsInline = true;
            video.width = this.settings.width;
            video.height = this.settings.height;

            video.addEventListener( 'play', function() {
                handler.trigger( 'play' );
            });

            video.addEventListener( 'pause', function() {
                handler.trigger( 'pause' );
            });

            video.addEventListener( 'canplay', function() {
                handler.showControls();
            });

            this.video = video;
            handler.setVideo( video );
            video.src = this.settings.videoUrl;
        },

        /**
         * Whether the video is paused.
         *
         * @return {boolean}
         */
        isPaused: function() {
            return this.video.paused;
        },

        /**
         * Pause the video.
         */
        pause: function() {
            this.video.pause();
        },

        /**
         * Play the video.
         */
        play: function() {
            this.video.play();
        }
    });

    /**
     * YouTube video handler.
     *
     * @memberOf wp
     *
     * @class wp.YouTubeHandler
     */
    YouTubeHandler = BaseHandler.extend(/** @lends wp.YouTubeHandler.prototype */{
        /**
         * Whether the handler supports a video.
         *
         * @param {Object} settings Video settings.
         * @return {boolean}
         */
        test: function( settings ) {
            return 'video/x-youtube' === settings.mimeType;
        },

        /**
         * Set up a YouTube iframe.
         *
         * Loads the YouTube IFrame API if the 'YT' global doesn't exist.
         */
        ready: function() {
            var handler = this;

            if ( 'YT' in window ) {
                YT.ready( handler.loadVideo.bind( handler ) );
            } else {
                var tag = document.createElement( 'script' );
                tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
                tag.onload = function () {
                    YT.ready( handler.loadVideo.bind( handler ) );
                };

                document.getElementsByTagName( 'head' )[0].appendChild( tag );
            }
        },

        /**
         * Load a YouTube video.
         */
        loadVideo: function() {
            var handler = this,
                video = document.createElement( 'div' ),
                // @link http://stackoverflow.com/a/27728417
                VIDEO_ID_REGEX = /^.*(?:(?:youtu\.be\/|v\/|vi\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/)|(?:(?:watch)?\?v(?:i)?=|\&v(?:i)?=))([^#\&\?]*).*/;

            video.id = 'wp-custom-header-video';
            handler.setVideo( video );

            handler.player = new YT.Player( video, {
                height: this.settings.height,
                width: this.settings.width,
                videoId: this.settings.videoUrl.match( VIDEO_ID_REGEX )[1],
                events: {
                    onReady: function( e ) {
                        e.target.mute();
                        handler.showControls();
                    },
                    onStateChange: function( e ) {
                        if ( YT.PlayerState.PLAYING === e.data ) {
                            handler.trigger( 'play' );
                        } else if ( YT.PlayerState.PAUSED === e.data ) {
                            handler.trigger( 'pause' );
                        } else if ( YT.PlayerState.ENDED === e.data ) {
                            e.target.playVideo();
                        }
                    }
                },
                playerVars: {
                    autoplay: 1,
                    controls: 0,
                    disablekb: 1,
                    fs: 0,
                    iv_load_policy: 3,
                    loop: 1,
                    modestbranding: 1,
                    playsinline: 1,
                    rel: 0,
                    showinfo: 0
                }
            });
        },

        /**
         * Whether the video is paused.
         *
         * @return {boolean}
         */
        isPaused: function() {
            return YT.PlayerState.PAUSED === this.player.getPlayerState();
        },

        /**
         * Pause the video.
         */
        pause: function() {
            this.player.pauseVideo();
        },

        /**
         * Play the video.
         */
        play: function() {
            this.player.playVideo();
        }
    });

    // Initialize the custom header when the DOM is ready.
    window.wp.customHeader = new CustomHeader();
    document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', window.wp.customHeader.initialize.bind( window.wp.customHeader ), false );

    // Selective refresh support in the Customizer.
    if ( 'customize' in window.wp ) {
        window.wp.customize.selectiveRefresh.bind( 'render-partials-response', function( response ) {
            if ( 'custom_header_settings' in response ) {
                settings = response.custom_header_settings;
            }
        });

        window.wp.customize.selectiveRefresh.bind( 'partial-content-rendered', function( placement ) {
            if ( 'custom_header' === placement.partial.id ) {
                window.wp.customHeader.initialize();
            }
        });
    }

})( window, window._wpCustomHeaderSettings || {} );
```

I tried erasing the whole following part or changing values of:

```js
supportsVideo: function() {
            // Don't load video on small screens. @todo Consider bandwidth and other factors.
            if ( window.innerWidth < settings.minWidth || window.innerHeight < settings.minHeight ) {
                return false; **(tryed: true) **
            }
```

Comment: Do you have more code related to supportsVideo? That function has to be called somewhere, can you show what happens in code if that function has been called?

Comment: Thanks for answer @Takkie253! 
I updated the post with the full wp-custom-header.js. BTW there's also a wp-custom-header.min.js and dunno if I have to modify it too in some way

Comment: If you edit `wp-custom-header.js` you would need to rebuild the assets otherwise `wp-custom-header.min.js` will not reflect your updated changes.  Also since this is within `wp-includes` this is part of WP Core and probably isn't the cause of your issue. It'll most likely be something within your theme files within `wp-content/theme`