# Validate youtube and other video site url

Tags: php, javascript

i want to provide a option for user to add video from the following video sites

1. Dailymotion
2. Metacafe
3. YouTube - [JavaScript REGEX: How do I get the YouTube video id from a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452546/javascript-regex-how-to-get-youtube-video-id-from-url/4811367#4811367)
4. Google Video
5. Hulu
6. Yahoo! Video
7. Vimeo - [Parsing a Vimeo ID using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916544/parsing-a-vimeo-id-using-javascript)
8. MySpace Videos

So would like to validate the data both in javascript as well as php. Do the url structure of these site change or they stay usually constant . Any suggestions are welcome .

EDIT: 
I have got some solution for a few and i have update the question . I want for others preferably Regex solution

Answer (score 2):

Lately youtube have provided link shortening features, so links like:

http://youtu.be/ol_75jFEpck are valid too.

So i guess this regex isn't 100% accurate any more )-: .

Answer (score 1):

There's a regular expression for YouTube URLs in the Closure Library:

/https?:\/\/(?:[a-zA_Z]{2,3}.)?(?:youtube.com\/watch\?)((?:[\w\d-_\=]+&(?:amp;)?)*v(?:<[A-Z]+>)?=([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+))/i;

http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/closure_goog_ui_media_youtube.js.source.html

Answer (score 0):

constant.

you should use regexp to validate url

usual url format:

```
this is not regexp :D
http://[domain].com/?[some GET letter like 'v']=[alphanumeric id][&other stufff..]
http://youtube.com/watch?v=aBcDeFg&embed=true#comment1
```

the id `?v=abcdefg` still the same all of the time, but this can be embedd, or maybe there is hash code in the url

Comment: thanks for youtube solution can u please give me the regex how about others

Comment: this is not regexp :) this is only a example. this is absolutely no regexp :D

Comment: sorry but i will not create these regexp-s for you :D this takes much time.